# How to align vertically an unknown sized image in a div

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a menu made of an `<ul>`. Every `<li>` has inside an `<a>`, and every `<a>` has an image and a label.
the image changes on hover (javascript) into a bigger image, so the size of the images is of no help. I would like to align the image vertically on the middle of the menu item. here you have the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
<!--
function changeImage(element, toReplace, withReplace) {
    var str = document.getElementById(element).src;
    document.getElementById(element).src = str.replace(toReplace, withReplace)
}
// -->
```

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Menu.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControls_Menu" %>
<ul id="navmenu">
<li><a id="default" runat="server" href="~/Default.aspx" onmouseover="changeImage('sideBar_Menu1_Image7', 'Calendar24x24.png', 'Calendar32x32.png');"
    onmouseout="changeImage('sideBar_Menu1_Image7', 'Calendar32x32.png', 'Calendar24x24.png');">
    <div class="divImage">
        <asp:Image ID="Image7" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar24x24.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="divLabel">
        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="CALENDAR" meta:resourcekey="Label6Resource1"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</a></li>


.divImage
{
    width: 29px;
    height: 29px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.divLabel
{
    float: left; 
    padding-top: 3px;
}
```

no matter what I do, align-vertically doesn't work...the only way I made things work was with tables, but then the click only works on the image, it doesn't on the lable too...I tried without divs too, can't find a way

Comment: one suggestion, if it is convenient, you can do your picture as an background-image, it is easy use image position to control center of the picture into one `div`.

Comment: Ths is not an asp problem, but a HTML/CSS problem. Would you paste some code that is generated in the browser? Best would be you create an example in jsfiddle

Comment: @HerrSerker - I thought as long as there are asp controls involved too, I will write asp as a tag too...people who know asp might know these kinds of things too...I didn't write WPF, as it has nothing to do with WPF, but with asp it has something to do (hence <asp:...

Comment: @bookie I guess your problem is a pure CSS problem. What you need is aproper presentation in the Browser. The Browser itself does not know about ASP, only about HTML/CSS. How you generate this HTML/CSS is of  absolutely no importance. So give an example in jsfiddle with the code that the browser sees.

Comment: @HerrSerker - of course the browser doesn't know about asp...but I thought when someone sees asp, can enter and read, maybe they know the answer...and about jsfiddle, never used or heard of it, but will give it a look tomorrow from work, maybe I can manage something, thanks for now

Comment: @bokkie http://jsfiddle.net/ is a great tool to post HTML, JS and CSS and edit and save it online, so we all can collaborate on it.

Comment: @HerrSerker - ok, I have tried, hope this is what you meant: http://jsfiddle.net/sftGT/    though the images are not shown, hope it helps you to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

edit 3
http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/td4jy/2/

---

edit 2
another proposal is
don't put them inside as `<img />` element but as `background-image` with `background-position: 10px 50%` or something

---

edit 1
http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/sftGT/1

---

orig
Don't use `float: left` floats are not vertically alignable. use `display:inline-block` instead together with `line-height` values.

Comment: :(( it doesn't work...I took out the label completly, only left the div with the image inside the <a> and changed the css as you said, float out, and instead used the display and the line-height and nothing changed with the image :(

Comment: Well, just have them on any server and give the URL to them in the code with `src="http://..."`

Comment: ok, I did, this is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/td4jy/1/ ; there is a comment in the html section where I gave the links to the "should be" printscreen and to the picture that should be on hover, cause I coulnd't do those withouth changing the original code...thanks